# How to send to multiple email recipients using php

Tags: php, email

I have problem receiving notification using bunch of email recipients, the only email received notification is the last email on the line  (email5@mysite.com) im been wondering why and what's the problem? Any help will be appreaciated.

```
<?php

class QIF_Email {

function send_email(){
    $to= "email1@mysite.com,email2@mysite.com,email3@mysite.com,email4@mysite.com,email5@mysite.com,";
    $subject="Inquiry";

    $header="mysite.com - Inquiry";

    $message="Date: ".$_POST['date']." \r\n";
    $message.="Name: ".$_POST['name']." \r\n";
    $message.="Company Name: ".$_POST['company_name']." \r\n";
    $message.="Contact: ".$_POST['contact']." \r\n";
    $message.="Address: ".$_POST['address']." \r\n";
    $message.="City: ".$_POST['city']." \r\n";
    $message.="State: ".$_POST['state']." \r\n";
    $message.="Zip Code: ".$_POST['zip_code']." \r\n";
    $message.="Telephone / Fax: ".$_POST['telephone']." \r\n";
    $message.="Email Address: ".$_POST['email_address']." \r\n";
    $message.="Comments: ".$_POST['comments']." \r\n";  
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);    


}



}

$qif = new QIF_Email;
$qif->send_email();


?>
```

Comment: This should be working. This is how you send to multiple addresses. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3478 Try getting rid of that trailing comma, though

Comment: dose it work with just 2 addresses? your hosts mail server may not allow this, check with them

Comment: You can also put all of those emails into an array and  then using a for each loop you could iterate through each instance of the array and invoke the mail function that way, but that would not be my first choice.

Comment: As mentioned below try and remove the last comma in the to string as that is not according to the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your recipients as an array and send the email to each one

```
class QIF_Email {

function send_email($to){
    $subject="Inquiry";

    $header="mysite.com - Inquiry";

    $message="Date: ".$_POST['date']." \r\n";
    $message.="Name: ".$_POST['name']." \r\n";
    $message.="Company Name: ".$_POST['company_name']." \r\n";
    $message.="Contact: ".$_POST['contact']." \r\n";
    $message.="Address: ".$_POST['address']." \r\n";
    $message.="City: ".$_POST['city']." \r\n";
    $message.="State: ".$_POST['state']." \r\n";
    $message.="Zip Code: ".$_POST['zip_code']." \r\n";
    $message.="Telephone / Fax: ".$_POST['telephone']." \r\n";
    $message.="Email Address: ".$_POST['email_address']." \r\n";
    $message.="Comments: ".$_POST['comments']." \r\n";  
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);    


}



}

$to[] = "email1@mysite.com";
$to[] = "email2@mysite.com";

for($i = 0; $i < count($to); $i++){
    $qif = new QIF_Email;
    $qif->send_email($to[$i]);
}
```

Not best practice but it should do the job

Comment: Thanks for the great help @user1672694... I truly appreciate it.